# How to display contact list programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, phone-number, contactscontract

I want to display the phone's contact log directly inside my application on a button click, in order to select a contact and its number. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. :)

```
String myData = "content://contacts/people/";
Intent myActivity2 = newIntent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( myData) );
startActivity(myActivity2);
```

or we can use

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```